# How to prevent Embarcadero C++Builder changing the bitmap code within the DFM all the time?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, dfm

I have to work with C++Builder. Depending on the mood, the IDE changes the hex-encoded bitmap property within the DFM file. Even if I have not changed anything within the GUI.

I'm using GIT and all the time this will result in a diff of the `.dfm` (which is ugly).

[image]

It is a VCL project with some Forms. The `Bitmap` value which will change randomly is from a `TImageList`.

Is there a way to prevent that the IDE will change the DFM all the time?

Comment: I have never seen this problem (and I also use Git for source control of all active projects). Is it just one specific bit map (in which case which component is it ?) or is it lots of different bit maps ? Is it a VCL or FireMonkey project. Which version of C++ Builder IDE is it ?

Comment: It's a VCL Project and a TImageList Component

Comment: You did not answer to @Roger's question about version of C++ Builder. So I ask the same. It would also be useful to know what the image type and number of colors per pixel of original images are, what the size of one image is and how many images there are. Have you been able to figure out any clues about when the changes occur (editing or not of the form with the list, what changes if any in other forms ...)? I know you said that you did not change anything, but still? Did you just open the project and close it again, or did you also compile / build / run, or not, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue.

Originally reported in XE, and closed as "Wont Do" (archived link):

[QC 92769: bitmap data of TImageList in dfm changes everytime the form is viewed as text (alt-F12)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220194129/http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=92769)

Then later, reported again in XE8, and closed as fixed in 10.3, at least for VCL:

[RSP-13666: Bitmap data of TImageList changes constantly](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13666)

So, to answer your question - make sure you are using C++Builder 10.3 or later, as the problem has already been corrected.

At least for VCL, anyway. There is a similar report still open for FMX:

[RSP-11259: Every FMX form save changes binary image data in FMX](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11259)

---

Some background info:

Internally, the `Bitmap` property is streamed through the DFM system using the [`TFiler::DefineBinaryProperty()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFiler.DefineBinaryProperty) method. This causes the DFM system to use an internal `TMemoryStream` for reading/writing the `Bitmap` data from/into the DFM.

`TImageList` does not actually hold a bitmap image, it holds a Win32 [`ImageList` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/image-list-reference) as an `HIMAGELIST` handle (stored in the `TImageList::Handle` property). The Win32 API deals with the actual bitmap internally.

When writing to the DFM, `TImageList` wraps the `TMemoryStream` with a `TStreamAdapter` to get a Win32 `IStream` interface, and then calls the Win32 `ImageList_Write/Ex()` function to write the `HIMAGELIST`'s data into the `TMemoryStream` (in a pre-ComCtrl32v6 format), and then the bytes in the `TMemoryStream` are written into the DFM.  The bytes `49 4C` at the beginning of the `Bitmap` data are an identifier for the Win32 API's `IL` stream format, and the bytes `42 4D` are an identifier for the actual bitmap image that the `HIMAGELIST` holds.

In your screenshot, there is only 1 byte being changed (in other past reports, there were more bytes being changed). According to [this WineHQ code](https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/comctl32/imagelist.c) (and various other 3rd party repos that I found), that changed byte belongs to the `ILHEAD::cGrow` field of the `HIMAGELIST`'s stream header:

> The number of images by which the image list can grow when the system needs to make room for new images. This parameter represents the number of new images that the resized image list can contain.

Which corresponds to the [`TImageList::AllocBy`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ImgList.TCustomImageList.AllocBy) property:

> Sets the number of images by which the image list grows when it needs to make room for new images.

When `TImageList` is writing its `HIMAGELIST` to the DFM, it first lets Windows write the `HIMAGELIST` data to the `IStream` however it wants.  Then, sometime between XE4 and 10.3 (I don't have sources to pinpoint the exact version), new logic was added to have `TImageList` then go back and overwrite the `cGrow` value with its own `AllocBy` value instead.  This was added to address this issue mentioned in RSP-13666:

> In the final comments of the previous issue, you noted that the root cause of the issue is that **the `ImageList_WriteEx` API seems to update an undocumented counter**. This agrees with my own investigation of the issue.

In that "previous issue" (QC #92769), it says:

> Wine writes an _ILHEAD struct, and the offending bytes from that struct that change are WORD cMaxImage, and WORD cGrow. These correspond to the number of images currently allocated in the list, and theoretically, how much the list will grow by once you add more than that amount. **Each time the image list gets streamed, it seems to increase cGrow by 4**, which makes me think that maybe Windows isn't actually using that field.

Which is exactly what you are seeing happen - the earlier `cGrow` value of `78 02` (632) being replaced with a new value of `7C 02` (636).

The QC ticket also says:

> It seems that **tweaking the stream after the fact and changing it to 0 doesn't immediately break it**. But like we said that seems risky

And:

> - **Unfortunately the issue that is reported is caused by native Win32 ImageList control, exactly found in the method ImageList_WriteEx(), that writes an image list to a stream. It is not a Rad Studio bug then its solution is not a simple fixing.**
> - There is a reported bug (ID: 428868) to Microsoft related to this problem but in VS

And, as noted above, `TImageList` does use `ImageList_WriteEx()` when writing to a DFM stream. And Embarcadero eventually decided to take the risk and patch the stream data that `ImageList_WriteEx()` writes.